# jQuery inside fancy box ajax not working -- init problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

This is my code to open a Fancybox that loads a page via ajax:

```
$('tr.record').click(function() {
    var record_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var link = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/expenses/expenses_edit/' + record_id;
    $.fancybox({
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'type': 'ajax',
        'href': link,
        'onClosed': function() {
            parent.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    $.bind("submit", function() {

        $.fancybox.showActivity();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success: function(data) {
                $.fancybox(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The page inside the fancybox has a form including a text field with char counter:

```
<form>
...

<textarea name="exp_det" cols="90" rows="12" id="exp_det"></textarea>
<span id="charLeft">150</span> characters left

</form>
```

The parent page loads this via header:

```
$('#ext_det').keyup(function() {
    var len = this.value.length;
    if (len >= 150) {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, 150);
    }
    $('#charLeft').text(150 - len);
});
```

So the issue is that this char counter (and other jQuery stuff like validation, datepicker) don't work inside the Fancybox. They do work if the page is loaded without Fancybox, or if it is loaded via Fancybox as inline.

I understand this seems to be a reasonably common question, but I tried all solutions and none worked for me.

I've tried

- using diferent IDs for the ajax page
- placing the char count script at the end of ajax page (it didn't even show
- on Firebug)
- placing the char count script as a function within `success`
- other crazy iterations

The problem seems related to re-init'ing the jQuery functions after the ajax page has loaded, since these elements were not there when the parent page was loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either rebind your event handlers once you have loaded content inside the fancy box or use the JQuery.live event binding mechansim. Your problem is occuring because your event handlers are trying to bind to DOM nodes that are not yet loaded, so what you need to do is either use the JQuery.live, which will bind events to elements even when they have not yet loaded OR use a callback function when your content of your fancybox has loaded to bind the event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ext_det').live('keyup', function() {

        // code to execute on keyup for element with id #ext_det    

    });
});
```

Comment: @zesimon - i tried `live` as well -- for some reason did not work -- could you give me a code example in case I'm using it wrong?

Comment: thanks - that's exactly what i tried (tried it again now) and it's a no go -- any idea why?

Comment: hang an a second ... your fancy box uses iframes to create the illusion of content being loaded in. The problem here is that the javascript event handlers you have defined in your parent window have nothing todo with your event handlers defined in your iframe. Can you try moving the code example I posted into the file that is actually being loaded with your fancybox and also making sure that that file is also loading JQuery.

Comment: zesimon - yes, that was something i had tried before (repeated it again now to be sure) - i put jquery to load via google cdn in the header of ajax page, and added the script before `</body>` - doesn't work. this is very annoying. interestingly, in Firebug I can't see the `<script>` tags containing the code you suggested.

Comment: ok i think i got it -- the solution was to combine a few of the things above: [1] reload my jQuery scripts (not jquery.js) before `</body>` in ajax page *AND*  [2] change IDs for elements of ajax page that duplicated those on parent page -- thanks zesimon for pitching in and giving some advice!

Comment: no problem ... sorry about not replying for a little while I had to attend a meeting at University